# Error in installing grpc extension for PHP

Tags: php, grpc

I'm trying to run the quick start for gRPC in PHP ([Quick start | PHP | gRPC](https://stackoverflow.com)). When I download the grpc extension for php (which is a prerequisite to run the quick start), I get the following error message at the end:

```
...
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.8/pecl/20220829/grpc.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.8/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.8/pecl/20220829
```

To download grpc extension, I'm following the instructions on this link [https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.57.0/src/php/README.md](https://stackoverflow.com) and using the command `sudo pecl install grpc`.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

(I tried looking up the file mentioned in the error message. I found a file named `System.php` that was downloaded a while ago when I downloaded XAMPP. Since I haven't been using XAMPP, I deleted this `System.php` file and uninstalled XAMPP. But this didn't seem to solve the issue in any way.)

Comment: Why all your links leads to stackoverflow.com?